# Save Failed Negative Time Aptana Studio 3.4

Tags: aptana3

I have searched everywhere and cannot find a fix for this problem. Every time I try to save a file it says the Title -Aptana Studio 3.4. The only way I've been able to fix it is a full reinstall, and I shouldn't have to do that every two files saved.
Please help! D:

Answer (score 0):

actually the simple solution is to change the date/time of your files in some how , the simple way is to open these files with any other editor and change any thing and save again so it will get your current time and it will work very fine